# Vim not displaing the terminal output with ":!command"

Tags: python, vim

I have a leader key mapped to execute a python script but it only flashes the termial output when I have 'CR' at the end.

This flashes the terminal output and I can't see what the output was.

```
noremap <leader>x :!clear<bar>./chart.py<cr>
```

This works with enter but the clear command does not execute only the chart.py executes then I can see the output display 'Press ENTER or type command to continue'.

```
noremap <leader>x :!clear<bar>./chart.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<bar>` is a Vimscript command separator and not a shell command separator. What you actually need here is `;`.

This should work:

```
noremap <leader>x :!clear; ./chart.py<cr>
```